# Get full path of controller (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have written code to get the path to the controller. Here it is:

```
 string link = Url.Action(
            (string)RouteData.Values["Login"],
            (string)RouteData.Values["Clients"],
            Request.Url.Scheme);
```

But it returns `:/Clients/Sending?Length=4`

I need to return the full path

For example: `http://localhost:51542/Clients/Sending?Length=4`

How I can do this?

Comment: Get the host name using `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host` and prepend it to the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

The AbsoluteUri property includes the entire URI stored in the Uri instance, including all fragments and query strings.

```
Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
```

you can use like this